# Float to a dataframe

Tags: pandas, for-loop

I have a for loop where it calculates each yearly shares market capitalization:

```
    close_dec = close.resample("1y").ffill()
    for element in close_dec:
        x=0
        for i in close_dec[element]:   
            market_cap = shares[x] * i 
            x+=1
            print('Market Cap of', element,"{:,.2f}".format(market_cap))
```

but when I try to put the outputs into a dataframe it says that market cap is a float and it the last number in the output.
how can I convert it to a list or a dataframe so all numbers show?

Answer (score 0):

Does the output need to be a Dataframe and do you need to use Pandas at all?

I would suggest using a [Numpy array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

Instantiate an empty array before the loops like

```
market_caps = np.array([])
```

Then in the loop you could do

```
market_cap = shares[x] * i 
x+=1
print('Market Cap of', element,"{:,.2f}".format(market_cap))
market_caps = np.append(market_caps, market_cap)
```

If you must use Pandas, I would suggest using a [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) over a Dataframe.
The code would be similar, but you would use the Pandas Series instead.